# Maintaining two different Spring boot versions in single Maven package

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Let's say we have a shared-lib package. The pom for the same is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.project.microservice-a</groupId>
<artifactId>shared-lib</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>shared-lib</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>com.projects.lib1.Application</start-class>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
....
....
</project>
```

There are projects using above shared library, having following pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.projects.microservice</groupId>
<artifactId>accounts</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>accounts</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.project.microservice-a</groupId>
        <artifactId>shared-lib</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
....
<dependencies>
```

Then there is one special subsystem running on Spring-boot-starter-parent.1.3.5 as parent, which won't take shared-lib with Spring-boot-starter-parent-1.2.3.

For importing shared-lib with Spring-boot.1.3.5, we need to modify pom.xml with parent as Spring 1.3.5 version and then build. This causes maintenance issues while building all subsystems, as Jenkins CI builds all JARs from Github with master branch. We can specify a separate branch manually, but maintaining same code for two branch is plain repetition.

Can anyone suggest a solution, which IMO may be a way to achieve one of these:

1. Create a package embedding both Spring 1.2.3 and Spring 1.3.5, and specifying required dependency version in other subsystems.
2. Bulid original client package with Spring Boot 1.3.5, and force it to use older version of Spring boot when used a dependency in required subsystems.

Comment: I don't undestand your problem... do you want to have the same project with two different versions of Spring Boot depending of...? Is it a multimodule maven project?

Comment: @jcgarcia : Improved the question. And btw, there is shared project with two other projects use as a dependency, but both projects have different spring boot version. So I want shared-lib to be built in both version, without maintaining duplicate code.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say these are your dependencies for each project:

1. shared-lib:

   - spring-boot-foo:1.2.3
2. project-a:

   - shared-lib
   - spring-boot-bar:1.2.3
3. project-b:

   - shared-lib
   - spring-boot-baz:1.3.5

Now you want project-a to use 1.2.3 of all spring-boot libraries, and project-b to use 1.3.5, regardless of what spring-boot libraries shared-lib specifies?

Put the following in your pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <spring-boot.version>1.3.5.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

If your projects have a common parent pom.xml, you can put it there and simply change `spring-boot.version` value to something else per-project as you see fit. Otherwise you'll have to duplicate it.

Alternatively if this so-called BOM (`<scope>import</scope>`) doesn't work, you can list each dependency explicitly, e.g.:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-foo</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-bar</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-baz</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Read more about managing spring-boot dependencies: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html

**UPDATE:**

You can manage other dependencies the same way as necessary. For example:

```
<properties>
    <spring-data-releasetrain.version>Gosling-SR4</spring-data-releasetrain.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-releasetrain.version}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Note that this will allow you to select which dependencies to use for each module, but you cannot use both. Even if Maven could put both on classpath, Java would only pick one. If you need to use both at the same time during runtime, you'll have to use some kind of advanced ClassLoader that can do this. In that case you could look into OSGI, for example.

Comment: Updated my question to make it more descriptive. Would you still recommend the same solution ?
Besides, should I add your first suggestion to all projects or just to the projects using shared-lib ?

Comment: Yes, it does fit your use case. However, you should use the older version  (1.2.3) of dependency in shared lib, not the newer one (1.3.5). This is because it's unlikely that something working with 1.2.3 will be broken in 1.3.5, but it's quite possible that something working in 1.3.5 might not yet be available in 1.2.3. So build shared with 1.2.3 and let others dependency-manage it to 1.3.5 as necessary. I suggest adding this to dependency management section in all projects, as it will make your intent clear and make it easy to upgrade later by just changing a single property.

Comment: Getting [given error](https://gist.github.com/utmishra/1e0cd77ae1ed30e7e82bde1c5add460e) on using shared-lib in new spring microservice with your suggested dependency management code. 
POM [here](https://gist.github.com/utmishra/302179b5d3963ba2a6df18b8b0cd3dba)

Comment: It seems there are more inconsistencies for some reason. Can you check what libraries are added to your .war archive? Then you can simply verify that all libraries are of the correct version. For Spring-Data libraries, they should all be from the same release train, such as [Gosling](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Gosling) for Spring Boot 1.3.x.

Comment: BTW, sorry for possible confusion: You're using spring-boot-starter-parent as parent, so you shouldn't need to import spring-boot-dependencies separately - parent will already do this for you. In fact, spring-data version should also be managed by parent. If you .war still ends up with incorrect versions of some libraries (did you do mvn clean?), you will probably have to list those libraries explicitly with correct versions in dependency management section.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what's happening. If you build shared-lib with spring-boot-starter-parent 1.3.5-RELEASE, then it works, but if you use spring-boot-starter-parent 1.2.3-RELEASE then it returns the error I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Please check what libraries you're getting in the final .war - are all spring-boot libraries of version 1.3.5? What version is spring-data common?

Comment: Its using spring-data-commons.1.11.4.RELEASE compared to 1.9.2.RELEASE, which is being used by Spring boot 1.2.3. This may not be a spring-data-commons problem. Posted other dependencies [here](https://gist.github.com/utmishra/ccf987cfcd7b4e7abc71b9c0418f5a6c)

Comment: This means that spring-data is not being managed by your 1.3.5 parent for some reason. Since it's pretty much impossible to debug this via comments, I can only suggest using the same trick with dependency management import. I've updated my answer accordingly. Use "Gosling-SR4" for 1.3.x and "Evans-SR4" for 1.2.x. (By debugging I mean things such as trying to not use starter parent in shared library, etc.)